# Show that: $ \frac{n}{3} + \frac{n}{9} + \frac{n}{27} + … = \frac{n}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Kinda new to proofs over here. I need to show that:

> ${n\over3} + {n\over9} + {n\over27} + ... = {n\over2}$

The top part with the n's, it seems like n is always increasing by one, and by remembering the sum of the 1st n integers expression, the top part can be seen as:

> $1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = (n^2 + n) / 2$

The bottom part, I'm pretty sure is:

> $3 + 9 + 27 + ... + 3^n$

And this is where I'm getting lost. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Is it clear that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}\neq\frac{a+c}{b+d}$? Something about your language surrounding the third sum you've written makes me want to ask.

Comment: Sorry @alex.jordan, but my professor threw all these "finding patterns" methods and "sequence formulas" at us so quickly without explaining in depth on how to derive them. I just wanted to connect the dots as well as I could :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to show
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{27}+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}$$

And the left side is the convergent [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with sum $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$, as desired.

Edit: the sum of a geometric sequence is very well known and in reality you would simply have memorized the formula. the sum is $\frac{a}{1-r}$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the factor each term is multiplied by.

It is also obvious when you look at it this way:

$$\frac{a}{1-r}=a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots$$
because

\begin{align}
a&=(a+ar+ar^2+\cdots)-r(a+ar+ar^2+\cdots)\\
&=a+(ar+ar^2+\cdots)-(ar+ar^2+\cdots)\\
&=a
\end{align}
And of course this only works when $|r|<1$, otherwise the sum just blows up.

Comment: I find it really hard to try and evaluate the left side and figuring which expression works for every value. Is it basically trial and error or is there a certain technique involved in evaluating the left side?

Comment: See the edit. Also try googling "convergent geometric sequences"

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the in depth explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Using Infinite Geometric Series summation formula $$\dfrac13+\dfrac19+\dfrac1{27}+\cdots=\dfrac{\dfrac13}{1-\dfrac13}=\dfrac12$$

as here the common ratio is $=\dfrac13$ and $-1<\dfrac13<1$

Comment: Wait...so with future problems like these, I just have to try and figure out the root Geometric and Arithmetic Series summation formula patterns that are related and try to work from there?